# Java Script Error in xpath selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxhcU.png)Below is the script that I wrote, and it goes well with initial steps but it starts to stop working where I have to click and it opens a popup box where i have to send keys and click close.

```
package pages;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import appSetup_Maven.test.BaseClass;

public class UploadFile extends BaseClass {

    @Test
    public void logout() throws IOException {
        Login();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

        @Test
        public void uploadFile() throws Exception {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar-menu']/ul/li[5]/a/span[1]")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar-menu']/ul/li[5]/ul/li[4]/a/span")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='drives-gridview']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/a[1]")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='explorer-content']/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='folderName']")).sendKeys("Test");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='folderName']")).sendKeys("Test");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='createFolderForm']/div[3]/button[2]")).click();
    }
```

When execute above code, I got this Error:

> JavaScript warning: www.wwwww.com/assets/js/clipboard.min.js, line 1:
>   mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run
>   very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial
>   [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
>           ************************************************************
>           * Call to xpconnect wrapped JSObject produced this error:  *
>           [Exception... "[object Object]'[object Object]' when calling method: [nsIConsoleListener::observe]"  nsresult: "0x8057001c
>   (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_JS_OBJECT)"  location: "native frame ::
>    ::  :: line 0"  data: no]
>           ************************************************************
>           ************************************************************
>           * Call to xpconnect wrapped JSObject produced this error:  *
>           [Exception... "[object Object]'[object Object]' when calling method: [nsIConsoleListener::observe]"  nsresult: "0x8057001c
>   (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_JS_OBJECT)"  location: "native frame ::
>    ::  :: line 0"  data: no]
>           ************************************************************
>           JavaScript warning: , line 0: https://hq20m-161112.wwww.com:10036/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js
>   is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
>           ************************************************************
>           * Call to xpconnect wrapped JSObject produced this error:  *
>           [Exception... "[object Object]'[object Object]' when calling method: [nsIConsoleListener::observe]"  nsresult: "0x8057001c
>   (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_JS_OBJECT)"  location: "native frame ::
>    ::  :: line 0"  data: no]
>           ************************************************************
>
> Not sure why i am getting this error. All i am trying to do is to
>   click an element on the webpage, enter text in the popup and click the
>   button on the popup to close that popup box.

Comment: Where is `HTML` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For this: -** All i am trying to do is to click an element on the webpage, enter text in the popup and click the button on the popup to close that popup box.

**You need to do following things :-**

**1)** Once the pop-up is generated, switch to that pop-up

**2)** Now you can communicate with the elements present on that pop-up like text field where you are going to send keys.

**3)** Then click on button to close the pop-up

Code for this is :-

**1) After clicking on link, and when pop-up opens, write this.**

```
 Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
```

**2) To send data to the text field :**

```
   alert.sendKeys("Text");
```

**3) To close the pop-up :**

```
   alert.accept();
```

Or else you can use : **after opening the pop-up do this.**

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hi Rohit, Thanks for your response. I tried this but its not working. May be because its not an alert, but its a popup where i enter some text in the textbox presented to add folder name and then click create to created. Do you have any other inputs.

Comment: can you show me a screen shot and web code ? I think I can help you with this.

Comment: you can also mention the link of application, If it is good for you. It would be great if you do so. I can try writing the script.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, but  cant give the website URL here can i mail you ? Can you send me your e-mail.

Comment: added screenshot as well

Comment: sorry to say but .. I do not see your email in my inbox

Comment: I have added code in my answer .. try that too..n let me know if it works..

Comment: Rohit, I did try that code and it did'nt work, sorry would provide you the url later in the day today. Since I don't have access to my personal e-mail in the office.

Comment: Welcome..happy for you